# Django populating values in the same record whose foreign key has been set before

Tags: python, mysql, django

i have this django app a part of whose models.py is shown below:

```
class user(models.Model):
    uid=models.IntegerField(unique=True,default=0)
    uname=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email=models.EmailField()
    password=models.CharField(max_length=20)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"{} {}".format(self.uid,self.uname)

    class Meta:
        db_table="user"


class userresp(models.Model):

    uid=models.ForeignKey(user,to_field='uid',null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    resp=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    datetime=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"{} {}".format(self.uid,self.datetime)

    class Meta:
        db_table="userresp"
```

a part of view.py

```
def plogin(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        username=request.POST['username']
        password=request.POST['password']

        if username and password:
            username_exist=user.objects.filter(uname=username,password=password)

            if not username_exist:
                return render(request,'student/loginfailed.html',)
            else:
                username_exist=user.objects.get(uname=username,password=password)
                userid=user.objects.values_list('uid', flat=True).get(uname=username)
                rep=userresp()
                rep.uid=user.objects.get(uid=userid)
                rep.save()
                return render(request, 'student/loggedin.html', {'username': username_exist,'userid':userid})

    return render(request,'student/plogin.html',)
```

here i have populated the "uid" foreign key field of "userresp" table as i login the user. now i want to populate the "resp" field in another view after this happens. But this "resp" has to be in the same row that has "uid" which i entered previously in "plogin" view. How can i do it in this view?

```
def mainpage2(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        response = request.POST.get("audio1", None)

        if response in ["1"]:
            return HttpResponse("you are right!")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Oops! you got it wrong.")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("invalid user")

//audio1 are a set of radio buttons in my template
```

Comment: You should __really__ use the builtin `contrib.auth` app instead of reinventing the square wheel. Storing unencrypted passwords is a __huge__ security breach, and there are numerous other pitfalls and security issues in building an even half-decent half-secured login/session system. Django provides a working, maintained and battlefield-tested one, so save your time (and your user's data) and use it.

Comment: i have many types of users who would login separately...so i have to use it this way only..

Comment: That's not a reason not to use the built-in auth.

Comment: I have written many django projects that had many "types" of users that could even authenticate from different sources (sso, ldap, external webservices, whatever) and `contrib.auth` has always been able to handle my needs. Believe me: you do _not_ have to "use it this way only". Now if you prefer to get your user's password stolen and their accounts on other sites hacked (fact: users are lazy and use the same passwords everywhere and never change them), well, your choice. Your responsability might be engaged when it happens too, so make sure you have a good insurance.

Comment: okay..got it..it seems i'll better go around the django admin way!

Comment: Tbh, having users login under different base urls is a royal pain in the behind, since `django.contrib.auth.urls` doesn't support namespaces and urls are obtained from settings as well (LOGIN_URL in AccessMixin). See for example how `django.contrib.admin.sites` sets them up if you want to support it.

Comment: can i make a signup page too using this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Considering your comments, here is the answer for the Django way:

If you use Django's `contrib.auth` - and unless you build on top of existing database tables that prevent you from using it (which raises the question why in this case you would use Django in the first place) there is no reason whatsoever to use Django and *not* use `contrib.auth` (because that would be one of the biggest benefits of using Django):

tl;dr

In Django, you create views for the pages you want to present your users. If they are required to login you simply declare it so. For example by wrapping the view declaration in your `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^board/$', login_required(DashboardView.as_view()), name='dashboard'),
]
```

Everything else including redirects etc. is handled by Django built-in. To style the login page to your look&feel, create a template in the template dir at the location required by `contrib.auth` (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator for details).

There are modules supporting double opt-in, e-mailing, social media etc. like for example django-allauth.

Authenticated users are stored in the session as instance of `django.contrib.auth.models.User`.

To get a handle on the `User` instance of the currently authenticated user of the request call `self.request.user` in your view.

Create a model that references `User` (1:1 relation) to store additional user data like profile settings etc. or check django-allauth et. al. for their profile settings. (They already support avatars and such stuff.)

You can also check for permissions. All model objects have automatically created different essential permissions that already cover most needs. You can of course create your own special permissions on top.